# Regex to get substring repeat in a string

Tags: regex

I have strings like this "$a477tr.: $bBìa mềm ; $c13x18.8cm" and I wanna get the all substrings after $a, $b, $c, ... . The expected results (included space):

```
$a "477tr.: "
$b "Bìa mềm ; "
$c "13x18.8cm"
```

I've used regex101 and tried the pattern but the result I got is

```
$a "477tr.: $bBìa mềm ; $c13x18.8cm".
```

I've tried some other patterns but I couldn't get the right results.

Please help.

Comment: `and I wanna get the substring after $[a-z0-9]` i'm not quite following what substring is it. Do you just want to split the input into groups which start with `$` symbol?

Comment: Yes I do. I would like to capture the string after $a, $b, $c ...

Comment: You're my hero. I tried \$[a-z0-9]?(?=(\$|$)) to define the character after the $ is a-z or 0-9 but I got empty results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=\$[a-z0-9])(?<content>[^\$]*)` [should do](https://regex101.com/r/6d11HN/1) the job.

`: "${content}"\n` - [the substitution pattern if needed](https://regex101.com/r/5d7NtS/1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with regex101, but in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) this pattern works:

```
(\$[a-z])([^$]+)
```

At this site, you have to choose `List` in `Tools` and write this:

```
$1 "$2"\n
```

After that, you will have this output:

```
$a "477tr.: "
$b "Bìa mềm ; "
$c "13x18.8cm"
```